# Use direct connection from Java application to Mysql Workbench? Or create a Php/Java server between to deliver data?

Tags: java, php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am developing multiple user desktop application in Java. I have modeled.implemented and populated my Database model in MySQL Workbench.

I'm worrying about to do:

1. How to get data from my database to my Java application?
2. My application needs to be secure. Should I use the direct
   connection to MySQL or should I create an additional server to
   deliver data? If so, what kind of server(Java, Php)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can easily get data from your database using java JDBC driver. Here's how
   https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database
2. Java JDBC is secure from Sql Injections if you use it properly. As
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291601. Making additional server is redundant and can also pose security issues.